# How to get value by index in jinja2 list?

Tags: javascript, python, django, plotly, jinja2

I am using plotly to make multiple graphs and django framework to present the graph to user.
I am storing all the graphs in list, example: all_graphs=[graph1, graph2]
I need to show only one graph at a time according to value selected in dropdown in HTML.

I am using javascript and jinja2 element for the same.
Below is my javascript code:
`

```
function graphshow(s){
      var id=Number(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
      var graph1 = {{ all_graphs.0 | safe}};
      Plotly.plot('id_of_div_to_show_graph', graph1, {});
    }
```

`
The above code works perfectly but when i replace 0 in line 2 with 'id' which is the index value of graph to be shown the code doesn't work. The value stored in 'id' is correct i've already checked.

Comment: `{{ all_graphs.0 | safe}}` is executed server side, while Javascript is executed client side, so you cannot do it this way. What you can do is to store all the grapes in a JSON array inside a Javascript variable, and then select the correct graph out of the populated Javascript variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε How can I store all the grapes in a JSON array inside a Javascript variable, and then select the correct graph out of the populated Javascript variable? I've used the program `function graphshow(s){
      var id=Number(s[s.selectedIndex].id);
      var graph1 = {{ all_graphs | safe}};
      var graph2 = graph1[id]
      Plotly.plot('secondary_graph', graph2, {});
    }`   But using this program doesn't show the graph